# In XML layout files, what's the difference between "remove=true" and "display=false"?

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm in the process of setting up a theme and have hidden several default elements (breadcrumbs, for example).

Some guides recommend:

`<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />`

whereas others go with:

`<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" display="false" />`

As far as I can tell these do the exact same thing. Does anyone know if there's a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Attribute : remove 
Value     : true/false
```

- Allows to remove or cancel the removal of the element. When a container is removed, its child elements are removed as well.
- The `remove` attribute is optional and its default value is false.
- This implementation allows you to cancel removal of a block or
  container in your layout by setting remove attribute value to `true`

---

```
<referenceBlock name="block.name" remove="true" />
```

---

```
Attribute : display
Value     : true/false
```

- Allows you to disable rendering of specific block or container with
  all its children (both set directly and by reference). The
  block's/container's and its children' respective PHP objects are
  still generated and available for manipulation.
- The `display` attribute is optional and its default value is true.
- You are always able to overwrite this value in your layout. In
  situation when remove value is true, the display attribute is
  ignored.

---

```
<referenceContainer name="container.name" display="false" />
```

Comment: Thank you. So, more concisely: one method removes all child elements whereas the other one doesn't? Personally I think your answer should be a lot more succinct.